# Which is the geometric interpretation of the maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vectors

We consider the matrices \begin{equation*}A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \phi & -\sin \phi \\ \sin \phi & \cos \phi \end{pmatrix}, B:=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} , \ \ \ S:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

I want to give the geometric interpretation of the maps $\vec{x}\mapsto B\cdot \vec{x}$, $\vec{x}\mapsto S\cdot \vec{x}$, $\vec{x}\mapsto A^{-1}\cdot \vec{x}$ and $\vec{x}\mapsto B^{-1}\cdot \vec{x}$.

$$$$

Let's consider the map $\vec{x}\mapsto B\cdot \vec{x}$.

We have that: \begin{equation*}B\cdot \vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2x_1 \\ x_1+x_2\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

Now we consider the map $\vec{x}\mapsto S\cdot \vec{x}$.

We have that: \begin{equation*}S\cdot \vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-x_2 \\ x_1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

To give the geometeic interprtation do we have to check the image of the unit square under these maps?

Comment: what kind of geometric interpretation are you looking for? e.g. for $S$ is this good enough? Rotate the axis in $90$ degrees to the left and reflect the initial point w.r.t to first coordinate.

Comment: Ok! And what about $B$ ? @pointguard0

Comment: There is no *simple* interpretation to this one, because there is this sum of two coordinates. 

In general, the transformation $y := Ax$ is a linear transformation that just changes the coordinate system. You can come back to the same coordinate system by applying the inverse transformation, namely apply $A^{-1}$ to $y$.

Comment: And what can we say about the map $\vec{x}\mapsto B^{-1}\cdot \vec{x}$ ? @pointguard0

Comment: Please check the image of the unit square under the map, and describe what happened in your own words. You will get a much better understanding from doing that than reading someone else's description.

Comment: For the matrix $B$ we get that the image of the unit square is : https://ibb.co/gSPdKb7 So this map transform the square into a parallelogram that is rotated, or not? @PaulSinclair

Comment: Use different colors for the edges of the original square.

Comment: Not rotated - sheared. Think of a stack of cards, where you push the top of the stack to one side while holding the bottom in place and keeping the sides straight. Or perhaps a cube of jello when you push the top to one side. That is called a shear transformation.

Comment: But it is not just one linear transormation, is it? It must a composition. Is it maybe a composition of shear, scaling and rotation? @PaulSinclair

Comment: It is a combination of shear and scaling. The $x$ direction is magnified by $2$, then the $y$-direction is sheared to a $45^\circ$ angle. You could also consider it a combination of magnification in the $x$-direction, contraction by $1/\sqrt{2}$ in the $y$-direction, $45^\circ$ shear in the $x$-direction, and a rotation of $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise, but that is a more involved description. There are other combinations (infinitely many, in fact) that will produce the same result, but the simplest is magnification in $x$ and shear in $y$.

Comment: I see!! What about the map $\vec{x}\mapsto A^{-1}\vec{x}$ ? We have that \begin{equation*}A^{-1}\cdot \vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \phi & \sin \phi \\ -\sin \phi & \cos \phi \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} Can we see that using again a graph without having a specific $\phi$ ? @PaulSinclair

Comment: Without a specific $\phi$? No. You need actual numbers to graph. You could try graphing it for a number of values of $\phi$. After a few, it should be very clear what this matrix is. (As a hint, it is a single operation from (scale, shear, rotate, reflect) instead of a combination.)

Comment: Ok! I will do that! As for $B^{-1}$ : The square will be minimized in the $x$-direction by $\frac{1}{2}$ and then the $y$-direction is sheared to a $-45^{\circ}$ angle. So it is a composition of shear and shrink. Is that correct? @PaulSinclair

Comment: Yes, though only because my earlier description of $B$ was not completely accurate. I should have had the shear come first, then the magnification (doing it in the other order does not produce the same result). In general, if you express a matrix as a sequence of standard actions $E_1, E_2, E_3$, etc., it means you are writing it as a product: $M = E_3E_2E_1$. Inverting it results in a reverse product of the inverse actions $M^{-1} = E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}E_3^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

"To check the image of the unit square under these maps" implies to check the [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis). Indeed, the standard basis for $\mathbb R^2$ is:
$$E_2=\{e_1,e_2\}=\left\{{1\choose 0},{0\choose 1}\right\}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
Hence, the transformed basis is:
$$S\cdot E_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}=S=\left\{{0\choose 1},{-1\choose 0}\right\}=\{s_1,s_2\}$$
Hence, the given vector $\vec x={x_1\choose x_2}$ in base $E_2$ will be scaled in $S$:
$$\vec{y}=S\cdot E_2\cdot \vec x=S\cdot \vec x=x_1{0\choose 1}+x_2{-1\choose 0}={-x_2\choose x_1},$$
which is the rotation by $90^\circ$ counterclockwise:

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

For $B=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$:
$$\vec{y}=B\cdot E_2\cdot \vec x=B\cdot \vec x=x_1{2\choose 1}+x_2{0\choose 1}={2x_1\choose x_1+x_2},$$

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

which is the [vertical shear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping).

See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Examples_of_linear_transformation_matrices) for the examples of linear transformation matrices.

Answer (score 0):

For the first example stated in simplest terms

$$ (x,\quad y)\rightarrow  ( 2x, \quad x+y ) $$ is a *transformation function* just like geometrical form changes like  reflection, magnification, sliding, shear etc.

Applying the above *Rule of transformation*

$$ (0,\quad0)\rightarrow  (0,\quad0) $$
$$ (0,\quad 1)\rightarrow  (0,\quad 1) $$

$$ (1,\quad 0)\rightarrow  (2,\quad 1) $$
$$ (1,\quad 1)\rightarrow  (2, \quad 2) $$

It maps a square to a parallelogram with rotation of elements parallel to x-axis by a shear angle $\tan^{-1}\dfrac12$  and a linear magnification of $ \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2},$

etc..